# Difference in I2C Reading Arduino and Raspberry

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, connection, i2c

I tried to read my sensor data from my Raspberry Nano W(2017) via I2C and UART, but without success. Afterwards I tried via my Arduino Uno R3 and here it worked. 
I am not that familiar with the SW-Differences, but is there the possibility, that the EEPROM on my Sensor only works with Arduino and is not compatible with the Raspi I am using?
Or I am just too stupid to get it running via my Raspi?

BR

Comment: Maybe you can give more details of how your hardware and software setup looks like for each case. Then we might be able to spot the missing piece

Comment: And don't forget to mention the sensor you're using in particular

Comment: Please post your code for raspberry pi so we can help. "Not Working" is not enough.